# How to use max() function to retrieve the most recent row using SQL / postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data set that looks like this 
[example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GEop.png).

There are multiple users under one domain. I want only one row per email_domain and the row should correspond to the max(last_login) value. In short I only want the user from the email_domain who was the last to log in among all users from the same domain.

Ive tried a query which looks like this

```
select *
FROM
(
select LOWER(SUBSTRING(ua.email FROM POSITION ('@' IN ua.email) + 1)) AS email_domain, last_login, last_name, first_name, email, phone  
from user_with_address ua 
order by email_domain
) as A
group by email_domain, last_login, last_name, first_name, email, phone  
having last_login = max(last_login)
order by email_domain
```

I still get a list with multiple values for each email domain, what am I doing wrong? Please help.

Disclaimer: I have basic->intermediate knowledge of SQL.

Comment: You're grouping by last_login, probably want to select max(last_login) and not group by it? Also grouping by name, email, phone etc will separate records from the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (email_domain) *
FROM (
  select lower(split_part(email, '@', 2)) AS email_domain, 
         last_login, 
         last_name, 
         first_name, 
         email, 
         phone  
  from user_with_address
) as A
order by email_domain, last_login desc;
```

I also incorporated Patrick's suggested to simplify the expression to extract the domain from the email.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly, ordering by last_login desc and picking the first row using distinct.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and retain the most recent login record for each group of same email domain records.

```
SELECT t.email_domain, t.last_login, t.last_name, t.first_name, t.email, t.phone
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.email_domain ORDER BY a.last_login DESC) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING(ua.email FROM POSITION ('@' IN ua.email) + 1)) AS email_domain,
               last_login, last_name, first_name, email, phone
        FROM user_with_address ua 
    ) a
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.email_domain
```

Note that I actually subquery twice here, to avoid having to repeat your code which computes the email domain.  If not for that, we could have accomplished this with just a single subquery.  We can use a single subquery here, but the query would be a bit harder to read.

Comment: Use `split_part(ua.email, '@', 2)` instead of `substring(ua.email FROM position(...) + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you. this makes more sense and is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I like Tim Biegeleisen's answer, but this is a little more simple, SQL wise. Don't know about performance differences though.

```
select 
  LOWER(SUBSTRING(ua.email FROM POSITION ('@' IN ua.email) + 1)) AS email_domain, 
  last_login, 
  last_name, 
  first_name, 
  email, 
  phone  
from user_with_address ua 
where last_login = (select max(last_login) 
                    from user_with_address ua2
                    where LOWER(SUBSTRING(ua.email FROM POSITION ('@' IN ua.email) =
                          LOWER(SUBSTRING(ua2.email FROM POSITION ('@' IN ua2.email))
order by email_domain;
```